# What kind of valve is this and how do I disconnect it?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, valve, hose

So, I have a leaky faucet. I am in the process of disconnecting everything so that I can take the faucet out and inspect what's going on with the leaky faucet. However, when disconnecting the faucet, I encountered a t-valve that I don't recognize (picture below) and am not entirely sure how to disconnect the hose without damaging it. This is connected to the hot water, and to the dishwasher. I have disconnected the cold water without issue.

Both of these hoses run all the way into the faucet, there is no other section to disconnect them from.

My primary inclination would be to just yank, but I don't want to attempt that without first figuring out if it's a bad idea, or if I shouldn't be worrying about it since I might wind up having to replace all of the hoses anyhow.

Any ideas?

### Mystery Valve

[image: Mystery Valve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had good luck getting these fittings to release with an open end wrench. Slide a wrench the same size as the outside diameter of the tubing over the tubing. Then use it to push in the release collar. It works well in tight areas or where the fittings are close together. If you have to replace any tubing a clean cut is required to get a good seal.

Comment: Yep, this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

It's a quick-connect t-fitting, not a valve.  You should be able to push down on the little lip at each connection and pull the hose loose.  Or you can just cut each hose and replace it with a new fitting.  You just push the hose in until it clicks and you're done.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know how to google for this, so knowing its name is incredibly helpful.